# What CMS is more suited for creating a directory list website?

Tags: content-management-system

What CMS is more suited for creating a directory list website?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of web-directory scripts all over Internet.
As far as I know, [Esyndicat](http://www.esyndicat.com/) and [PHP Link Directory](http://www.phplinkdirectory.com/) are the most popular proprietary scripts for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that by directory the ask-er is referring to a directory listing script like yellow pages, and for that i'd rather suggest Joomla!! as a CMS, it has excellent free plugins/components which will serve the ask-ers purpose put of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a listing of files and directories on your filesystem, your web server (apache, IIS) will give you that very easily. If not, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Actually this is for a directory listing site, like yellowpages listing, not directory structures.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with [esyndicat script](http://www.esyndicat.com). It has the most full set of features at the moment.